# Python how to reference variable

Tags: python

I'm getting a problem when referencing variables on a python file. Here is the code:

```
FG_E = 9
FG_R = 8
START = 7
READY = 9
MC = 3
BRAKE = 5
ERROR = 6
a = 2
b = 3

position = 0

def build_message(signal):
    message = position
    message = message | (0b1<<signal)
    s = bin(message)
    s = s[2:len(s)]
    s = (16-len(s))*'0' + s

    s0 = s[0:len(s)/2]
    s1 = s[len(s)/2:len(s)]
    s0 = s0[::-1]
    s1 = s1[::-1]
    s_final = int(s0 + s1, 2)
    position = s_final
    print bin(s_final)
    return s_final

build_message(FG_R)
```

The error I get is:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'position' referenced berofe assigment

Comment: give `global position` inside function before using `position` variable

Comment: for more understanding see http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php

Comment: Please give your variables meaningful names.

Answer (score 3):

The problematic line is actually `position = s_final` in the function `build_message`.

If it wasn't there then `message = position` would work because the Python interpreter would know to which `position` variable you are referring.

But in this case it is ambiguous because you're are later reassigning to `position` (`position = s_final`).

You should either re think the design of the code, or add `global position` as the first line in `build_message`.  Keep in mind that as it says, it would make `position` a global variable and `build_message` will change the value of `position` every where throughout your code.

**EDIT** A quick demo:

```
global_var = 0

def foo1():
    print(global_var)

def foo2():
    print(global_var)
    global_var = 1

def foo3():
    global global_var
    print(global_var)
    global_var = 1
    print(global_var)

foo1()
>> 0

foo2()
>> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'global_var' referenced before assignment

foo3()
>> 0
   1
```

Comment: Why Python behave like this? means `message = position` it would work we can not assign anything to `position` until it is declared as global.

Comment: @KalpeshDusane Because it creates an ambiguity. Without `position` being `global`, `position = s_final` can't tell if you are trying to create a new, local `position` variable or if you meant to assign to the global `position` variable.

Comment: So if we do not use `global` then value of `position` in this statement `message = position` is zero or not?

Comment: @KalpeshDusane It is `0`, as long as there's no line that reassigns `position` to something else below that. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `global` keyword to access global variable.

```
def build_message(signal):
    global position
    message = position
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an outside variable into a function maybe you should consider passing it as an argument, like:

```
def build_message(signal,position):
    pass
```